# Creating or modifying XSLT by visible editor

Tags: html, xslt, ckeditor, tinymce

We have ckeditor or tinymce wysiwyg editor for HTML.

I have complex xslt code for providing styles to XML, it's very difficult to modify XSLT code every time.

I need visible editor for modify XSLT code and I tried to modify tinymce editor code for support to xslt tags, Some how I achieved that but facing lot's off issues into that.

I create custom tags for xslt, that loads xslt tags but it's removing xslt attributes and conditions.

Anyone knows how we can achieve xslt visible editor or is there any visible editor for XSLT ?

Thanks